# Existence of a bijection between nat and nat * nat in Coq

Tags: coq

While reading the book 'Computational Type Theory and Interactive Theorem Proving with Coq' by Gert Smolka, on page 100 on Semi-Decidability (Fact 13.1.6) it appears that I need to use a bijection between `nat` and `nat * nat` and rather than assume the existence of a function `f:nat -> nat * nat` and `g:nat * nat -> nat` which are inverse of each other with an `Axiom`, I wanted to prove such existence as a side exercise. I assume this should be possible with nothing more than Peano arithmetic. However, it appears to be a lot more involved than I was prepared to invest in time and effort (in part because the most common approach taken as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781594/bijective-function-from-n-to-n-x-n) involves square roots, integer parts, and real numbers). So I was wondering if there was an elementary way to define these functions `f` and `g` in Coq as well as proving correctness (`forall (n:nat), g (f n) = n` etc.). I would be happy if this was available within the Coq library too. If not, I'll resort to an `Axiom` in the interest of time.

Comment: I think a relevant answer was already given on Coq's discourse https://coq.discourse.group/t/bijections-between-nat-and-nat-nat/720

Comment: @kyodralliam Yes the exact same question was asked there. I will check out the answer. Thank you !